# How to get comment box of an image in user's profile, into my facebook application

Tags: php, html, facebook

I have created an application using php which upload images into user's profile.After image is uploaded, User is directed to another page which display the uploaded image. Here I need to display comment box of the image including comments posted by friends.
 
I have fully access to the uploaded image(id of the image,source,link,etc.)
I tried this with usual facebook comments plug-in which is given bellow.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:comments href="APP_URL" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```

I tried replacing **APP_URL** with
 
1) **source** link of the image eg: http://a5.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v5041/89/51/40796308305/n40796308305_1960517_6704612.jpg
2) **facebook link** of the image eg: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=1960517&id=40796308305
(above links are just examples taken from facebook developer page)

but non of them do what I want.It display the comment box.But after I posted a comment,it is not available in users profile page(it doesn't update the image comment box which is in users profile)
Can anyone please help me with this?
I need to get the comment box of a image into my facebook application.
**Or if there is a way load whole image display page(image,comment box,Tag This Photo button,Share button,etc.) inside my app window, please let me know**

Answer (score 1):

The comments dialog is intended to be used with a photo posted to Facebook, but intended to be a simple comments plugin for websites. In order to do what you want, you'll have to use the graph api:

This will get you the photo, where the number at the end is the id:

> http://graph.facebook.com/40796308305

Adding comments to the end (with a valid access_token from your app) will get the comments for the photo:

> http://graph.facebook.com/40796308305/comments

You can also post to this url to allow users of your app to add comments to the photo. Here's the link for the graph API with photos: [Photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Hope that helps!

### **Edit for more clarity:**

Okay check it out, I can do to my profile feed at (I added an access_token to the hyperlink):

> [http://graph.facebook.com/me/home](https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=2227470867|2.AQA3thwXGCH6bYFd.3600.1311202800.0-6400518|XfIWN4FNF9R-jf8JTbu3XkfpFoQ)

I get a result that looks something like this (truncated):

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "6400518_2123759246396",
         "from": { ... },
         "to": { ... }
         },
         "message": " ... ",
         "picture": "https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/####.jpg",
         ....
         "type": "photo",
         "comments" : { ... comments are here ... }
```

### What does this mean?

Using this data you can see that the post on my wall with id **6400518_2123759246396** has the **type: photo**, so you know it is a photo. Furthermore, you can get the comments on the photo by accessing the **comments : { .... }** data.

If you would like to allow users to add more comments to this post. You would need the users to have authenticated your app with the correct permissions ( see the documentation on [publishing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#publishing) for more info on that). Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,friend I know how to get the details of an image,and access the comments for a image using above graph api methods.But the problem is those are returned as text.I need to display comment box of an uploaded image including comments posted for that image **just as it is shown in facebook**.

Comment: I'll make this simple, Is there a way to display comment box of my image(image which is in my profile) in my facebook application including posted comments.**comment box should look like same as it is in facebook**

Comment: I added more info that should help you out.

Comment: Friend I think you still didn't get my point.Either you didn't get it or I didn't get your answer:-).
Just simply say me is there a way to use facebook social plunging comment box to post a comment to my profile picture.
meanwhile please go to this link.Here I have asked same question in a different way.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761250/is-there-a-way-to-load-a-facebook-page-inside-my-facebook-application-canvas-page)

Comment: It is not possible to use the social plugin to directly comment on a profile picture.